# Probability Question on twins -- found this on a mu test

Tags: probability, self-study

> 4)    Twelve twins are participating in a tournament. The 24 people are randomly assigned to groups of 3. What is the expected number of twins in the same group?

```
a)  23/24
b)  24/23
c)  1
d)  3/2
e)  NOTA
```

This is the solution:

> B. Let $P(k)$ be the probability that any one group will have twins. $P(k)=(12\times 22)/{24 \choose 3} $. So the expected number will be $8P(k)=24/23$.

Where is $22$ coming from?

Comment: Since (by definition) $24 \choose 3$ counts the number of distinct groups, the numerator $12\times 22$ in the answer must count the groups with twins.  Once you suppose a group has twins, how many other possibilities are there for the third person in the group?  BTW, the phrasing of the question is confusing and ambiguous. If we take it literally as stated--the expected *number of twins,* rather than the expected number of *sets* of twins--then none of the answers is correct, because the right value is $48/23$.